# How to keep app running in background to mimic push notifications with an angular/firebase ios app

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, firebase

At the moment setting up a server to work with Apple Push Notification Service isn't something I want to do, yet I want to provide pop-up/push notifications even when my app is closed. Firebase already does a great job of pushing data down to a client when the app is running, so I figured If I can keep the app "running" in the background, it will still receive data, and then I could manually issue an alert/pop-up. Is this something I can configure cordova to do? Any insight/direction/recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using Parse push services?

Comment: Never heard of Parse, I can look into it....thanks. I'm looking for the simplest solution available as I am still prototyping....

Comment: Parse do have free push notification for small amount of traffic and is not hard to set up (even easier if you follow their guides). So I think it would work good for prototyping!

Comment: I've used [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) for push notifications and it's free. There's not restrictions for data and it come with [cordova plugins](http://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/phonegap-sdk-installation). Basically it does what you're asking for.

Comment: I'm taking a look at OneSignal today, thanks for the recommendations

Comment: Apple won't let you keep your app running in background unless it's using one of the allowed background operations (location, voipe, music playback), so, best option is to use push notifications